# A simple complex number inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

$\def\Re{\mathop{\mathrm{Re}}}$Suppose $z \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfies $-\dfrac{1}{2} < \Re(z) < \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $|z| \geqslant 1$, and $c$ and $d$ are integers.

Why is it that $|cz + d| \leqslant 1$ and $|c| \geqslant 2$ are inconsistent with each other?

I have tried using algebraic manipulations but am unable to show this.

Comment: Given that $|\text{Re}(z)|\leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $|z|\geq 1$ this should imply an inequality about $\text{Im}(z)$.  Next, note (*or try to prove*) the property that if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers then $|a+bi|\geq \max(|a|,|b|)$.  What is a bound on the magnitude of the imaginary part of $cz+d$?  What then is a bound on $|cz+d|$?

Comment: Can you conclude by the hint given? Let consider $c^2(1+2(d/c)Re(z)+(d/c)^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We can reduce to

$$|cz+d|^2=(cz+d)(c\bar z+d)=c^2|z|^2+cd(z+\bar z)+d^2=c^2|z|^2+2cdRe(z)+d^2 \ge c^2+2cdRe(z)+d^2 $$